# I'm trying to install InfyOm Laravel Generator in my project

Tags: php

After run **composer update** I get this error

Problem 1
- illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires infyomlabs/adminlte-templates ^3.0 -> satisfiable by infyomlabs/adminlte-templates[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.2 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.3 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.4 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.5 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.1 (conflict analysis result)
- infyomlabs/adminlte-templates[v3.0.0, ..., v3.0.3] require illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
- Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev], laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to install infyom laravel generator in my laravel project and i got the error i posted

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading your php version to 7 or use infyom for laravel 9